# Is there a word simplificate in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wonder if someone can expound on this word simplificate.

Is that a word one can use in English?

Comment: I think  "simplificate" is not a word, since its meaning would be the same as "simplify".

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to use it for, and with what intended meaning. Provide an example sentence and some context. Failing that, no, you cannot use that word.

Comment: *Simpificate* is a joke word you might use in a meeting to tease (or comment on) a speaker whose explanations or “simplifications” are overly complicated. Or you might use it after an “ideation session” in a sentence like: “Now that we’re done ideating, let’s simplificate.”  It’s like saying that you’re looking for something “on the intertubes” or “the google”. It’s funny in the right context, but definitely not a “real word”.

Comment: Thank you, Global Charm! This is exactly the kind of context I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of *simplicate*. Simplicate was coined by an American aeronautical engineer and adopted as a part of a mantra by the company owner in the form of "add lightness and simplicate". It is fairly well known in high performance vehicle engineering, be it planes, boats, or cars.

Note, the modern definition has drifted a bit from the original idea. It currently reads as a trade-off between design complexity and user simplicity. Originally, it was much more about design sophistication yielding less complex structures and lower control system loads.